# How to parseInt in angularjs expression

Tags: angularjs, expression, parseint

I have such type of condition:

```
<td ng-repeat="sal in name.salaries" 
    ng-if="name.avalue>sal.annual_value">
       Value must be less than or equal to Balance Amount
</td>
```

Whats happening in real scenario is

For Eg. `name.value=1200 sal.annual_value=42`
as its not parseInt thats why its considering `42 > 1200`.

How can I `parseInt()` in AngularJS expression?

Comment: name.avalue in ng-if shouldn't it be name.value like in your eg.?

Comment: just use simple `Number(name.value)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a scope function to make that verification:

```
{...}
scope.checkSalaries = function(avalue, annual_value) {
   return avalue > annual_value;
}
{...}
```

and in html:

```
<td ng-repeat="sal in name.salaries"
    ng-if="checkSalaries(name.avalue,sal.annual_value)">
       Value must be less than or equal to Balance Amount
</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `parseInt` within your `ng-if`:

```
<td 
    ng-repeat="sal in name.salaries"
    ng-if="parseInt(name.avalue)>parseInt(sal.annual_value)">
        Value must be less than or equal to Balance Amount
</td>
```

Or you can create a function to check this in your controller:

```
<td 
    ng-repeat="sal in name.salaries"
    ng-if="isGreater(name.avalue, sal.annual_value)">
        Value must be less than or equal to Balance Amount
</td>

$scope.isGreater = function(val1, val2) {
    return parseInt(val1) > parseInt(val2);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use `parseInt` method in the view you can define a `Number` $scope in your controller, and then user its built in method `parseInt()` in the view.

e.g.

Controller:

```
$scope.number = Number;
```

View:

```
<td ng-repeat="sal in name.salaries" ng-if="number.parseInt(name.avalue)>number.parseInt(sal.annual_value)">
Value must be less than or equal to Balance Amount</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try :

```
<td 
    ng-repeat="sal in name.salaries"
    ng-show="isGreater(name.avalue, sal.annual_value)">
        Value must be less than or equal to Balance Amount
</td>

$scope.isGreater = function(val1, val2) {
    return parseInt(val1) > parseInt(val2);
};
```